# SMTP ERROR : Could not authenticate

Tags: php

i am trying to use phpMailer to send confirmation messages to users via email. my code is this:

```
$SMTP_USERNAME = SMTP_USERNAME;
$SMTP_PASSWORD = SMTP_PASSWORD;
$SMTP_HOST = SMTP_HOST;
$SMTP_STATUS = SMTP_STATUS; 

    if($SMTP_STATUS==1)
    {

        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/modules/SMTP/smtp.php"); //mail send thru smtp
    }
    else
    {
        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        // Additional headers
        $headers .= 'From: '.$from.'' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Bcc: '.$to.'' . "\r\n";
        mail($from,$subject,$message,$headers); 
    }
```

but every time I load it, it displays this

Error msg: " SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Please help me out from these issue.

Thanks for your time guys, hope someone can get back to me soon!

Comment: Your error message is not the error a SMTP server would return. Whats the exact response from the SMTP server?

Comment: I've rollbacked your edit because it changes the question entirely and renders existing answers useless. The "edit" feature should be used to provide clarifications or further details, not to make a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The mail() function does not allow any kind of authentication. You need to switch to a third-party mail package that implements the required SMTP authentication (or write you own, which I wouldn't recommend). Typical choices include:

- [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected)
- [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)
- [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)